# MySQL - Pulling number of clients served per month

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a list of clients with start dates and end dates.  I want to pull a number of clients served on a monthly bases.

```
id    Start Date     End Date
1     2019-01-01     2020-01-01
2     2019-02-01     2019-03-01
```

So if I wanted to pull a query to say:

- in January of 2019 there were 1 client
- but February there is 2
- same for March
- however in April it would get me 1

Thanks for you time,

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Shouldn't March have just one client, since the end date of client is March first?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `union all` and window functions (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
select dt, sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by dt) cnt
from (
    select start_date dt, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select end_date, -1 from mytable
) t
group by dt
order by dt
```

If you want to count as active customers for the month whose end date is the first of the month:

```
select dt, sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by dt) cnt
from (
    select start_date dt, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select end_date + interval 1 month, -1 from mytable
) t
group by dt
order by dt
```

Note that this assumes that start and end dates are always on the first of the month, as shown in your sample data - otherwise a few adjustments are needed in the `union`ed subqueries.

---

If you want one record per month in the period, you can generate the list of dates with a recursive cte:

```
with d as (
    select min(start_date) dt, max(end_date) max_dt from mytable
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 month, max_dt from d where dt < max_dt
)
select d.dt, sum(sum(t.cnt)) over(order by d.dt) cnt
from d
left join (
    select start_date dt, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select end_date, -1 from mytable
) t on t.dt = d.dt
group by d.dt
order by d.dt
```